# Narrowing down to common JS methods and properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards, narrowing, type-narrowing

Is there a way to make this TypeScript narrowing less ugly (or more elegant ;-) ❓

With `IsSomething` type guard, I want to narrow down access
to common methods and properties of any JavaScript variable
which is *not* `null` and *not* `undefined` (things like `.toString`, `.valueOf`, `.hasOwnProperty`, `.constructor` etc.)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&module=1#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-b56RYmezx1r+cLxbTZYqd1TVfMxVr40ma0b2ZbQA)

```js
export type Something = 
  number | string | boolean | symbol | object | bigint;

export function IsSomething(value: unknown) : value is Something {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}

let a = [1, "2", 3];
Narrowing(a);
NotNarrowing(a);

function Narrowing(o: unknown) { // OK
    if (IsSomething(o)) {
      console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
    }
}

function NotNarrowing(o: unknown) { // NOT OK
    if (o !== null && o !== undefined) {
      console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not your question, but - it's possible for non-nullish values to not have `toString` etc, if one does `Object.create(null)`. (just something to look out for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, every value except for `null` and `undefined` is assignable to the so-called [*empty object type* `{}`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types).  So you can simplify your `Something` to just `{}` and your [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) will work the same as before:

```
export type Something = {};
function isSomething(value: unknown): value is Something {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}
function narrowing(o: unknown) { // OK
  if (isSomething(o)) {
    console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
  }
}
```

Furthermore, TypeScript 4.8 will introduce improved support for [narrowing `unknown`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing), after which your "NotNarrowing" function will start working, because checking `(o !== null && o !== undefined)` will narrow `o` from `unknown` to `{}` automatically:

```
// TS4.8+ 
function nowNarrowing(o: unknown) { // okay
  if (o !== null && o !== undefined) {
    console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKEC2wYAsCWAdgOZwC8cA3gL4DcAUPQGYCuhAxjPhIXPgM4ZseIsQAUANwCGAGxbAAXHDYBrQhADuhAJRLpc1APRYcBElXpw4UHCyi998uAEIyFNgBNgTIsA9wAMgC4R1RXCkIWGRkGakYZHDgpcjgAbQBGABo4ACIAJhzsgGYAXQZCKSgoTVExKW1yzQA5SuqNWvqGZjZObl4KqpqSMQglVXUtbSo4AHoZuAB5AGlLPiY4MQEhU1qIbSnKVat2Hn4IBIA6GQhxCAuYCDQYKFrtbLuTwn5nlk5oBtWcTi9DmcAAKmgACwXAAcAGo4N0OFweHAJi1Bu1hqNlIQ1JodNNQRAVFJEKt8OsRi43GiojJAsEIDT3IQvD5CH4Dkc4MzQTQeZ8zpdrrd7o9nq93hchT8-lAAVYgUA)

Comment: Thanks again, I've just found out that `Object` works too, exactly [how I want it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019825/1768303).

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz's excellent answer led me to the following solution:

```js
// With `IsSomething` type guard, I want to narrow down access 
// to common properties of any JS variable 
// which is not null and not undefined, like: 
// .toString, .valueOf, .hasOwnProperty, .constructor etc.

export function IsSomething(value: unknown) : value is Object {  
  return value !== null && value !== undefined;
}

Narrowing([1, 2, 3]);

function Narrowing(o: unknown) { // OK
    if (IsSomething(o)) {
      console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
    }
}
```

It turns out, TypeScript has a predefined `interface Object`, which works exactly the way I want:

[image: Object interface in TypeScript]

In TypeScript, the `Object` interface is different from the primitive `object` type, as the former is still assignable to any other primitive or complex type. It is also different from an empty type like `type Something = {}`, as the latter doesn't supports IntelliSense.

```js
// Object interface is OK
let a: Object = 42; 
let b: Object = true;
let c: Object = "string";
let d: Object = Symbol(42);
let e: Object = new class SomeClass { someProp = 42 };

// Empty type is OK but no IntelliSense 
let a1: {} = 42; 

// Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'
let a2: object = 42;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&module=1#code/PTAEHUEsBcAtQAYEkDOBlA9gWwKZ0gHYDmCo0AngA46hECuAhgE4AmANKEqAO4MHRkMoAsyYZuoFuIKgGAYzk4UKUACgQg0HOxYMMymOpNokJaAwAzWQXKgAUmlAA3ZpAYAjADY11YbrEg5eEgVAgwBAjpPT2sWYXDQOgIWHAtCHHZQT0gAaxwALjUNADpoDDRoJkIiDmKXTzocAHkLWtgGFCbuAgAFQxxjclrtAhRKujkyplA8OWLVVRwAD0oMY1ALJMnIPU50bDwA4gAKesbCpJyw7oBKUEKzmhDQJvcAKxxJ0ABvUDU-ph4OhMGSPUAAQgAvJDhFEYgAyeHOBgNGhQmFJFJpAgZADcqgAvgsAHKicTVY4AbQAjBwAEwcADMAF0bvjVJsCNtdqSmGJuBSMBcCFdpHdfhomgBpVR-SBWY6oTC4fAnDA3cWyv5aPQoDDeYqeDBEY4YUrlSoUm4cM0jMZMCZTNlaolE3wvd6fASEaADCzyJ4qaWqbwCBiFV4fL4wgAsdNxalDoHcEc90bIDpw+KTclTUYEMIARPbqoXs3hJHmvaAYWhyFh3PrjnHnUmCh78zXhDgJHJPB0VMqcABhfvKH6gPW4PoYShduOgAnsjQAUSwlAoZCogZeUuTdAiQiQ-Bw0UgaBwox8SYY1MK3wJ8-jandK75a0KABVt6AAOSRBsBl-UBnjCMNlEgIgRC8Ggyi3ag-wwNNoF-EMKwYOlCiQztY2fBZVCAA).

One subtle issue still remains. As @CertainPerformance [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016638/narrowing-down-to-common-js-methods-and-properties-in-typescript#comment128961461_73016638), the above won't work for an edge case like `Object.create(null)`, where an object is created which doesn't have *any* properties or methods, but isn't `null` either.

If that's a requirement, the following should do the job:

```js
// can be extended to check for toString, valueOf, etc
export function IsSomething(value: unknown) : value is Object {
  return (<Object>value)?.constructor !== undefined;
}

Narrowing([1, 2, 3]);

function Narrowing(o: unknown) { // OK
  if (IsSomething(o)) {
    console.log(o.toString(), o.constructor);
  }
}
```